# Highcharts: How to reduce padding for narrow bars?

Tags: highcharts

I have a grouped bar chart. After using `pointWidth` to reduce thickness of the bars, I can't find a right value for `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` to reduce the space between bars, and the space between groups.

Please see:
http://jsfiddle.net/theactiveactor/64ghpk1v/

Comment: Setting pointWidth will not give you a possibility to simply reduce space between bars and between groups. This is because pointWidth is normally calculated from pointPadding and groupPadding. I have made custom function for reducing space between bars, you can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7o0eq05L/17/  But as you can see the space between groups will still be present. To avoid this situation you can change plotArea height. I have made function that will give you this possibility: http://jsfiddle.net/7o0eq05L/16/